# I hope this riddle doesn't inspire resentment

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, poetry

I defy or gall,
by house or by wall.

Hint

> 5 letters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it

> Spite?

I defy or gall

> To spite means to go against someone's command or wishes with the intent to annoy or inconvenience them, and is often performed with gall.

by house or by wall

> A spite house or wall is constructed for the simple purpose of annoying the neighbors or city members (Thanks to @Rubio)

Comment: The second line is where the knowledge tag comes in. Maybe try looking to see if there's a combination of your proposed answer with the things in the second line that make sense.

Comment: @JProblems is this what you were thinking of?

Comment: @Bewilderer [this may help ...](http://www.webutils.pl/index.php?idx=rot&mode=rot13&dec=DECODE&data=Gnxr+n+ybbx+ng+uggcf%3A%2F%2Fra.jvxvcrqvn.bet%2Fjvxv%2FFcvgr_ubhfr+naq+uggcf%3A%2F%2Fra.jvxvcrqvn.bet%2Fjvxv%2FFcvgr_jnyy+-+chggvat+lbhe+jbeq+%22ol%22+gurfr+bgure+gjb+jbeqf+fubhyq+tvir+lbh+jung+lbh%27er+zvffvat)

Comment: @Bewilderer not quite, Rubio's got the missing piece in his link.